# SDLK_F1 key case not working

Tags: sdl

I am trying to catch the event for F1 key in SDL in C++.
But,somehow i cannot see any changes after pressing the F1 key.But,when i wnat to toggle my animation objects on the screen i make use SDL_t case to do so,and it is executing fine.
Just not geting why is it not taking the F1 key.
Here is the switch case for handling key press events:

```
SDL_Event event;

  bool done = false;
  bool keyPress = false;
  while ( not done ) {
    draw();
    SDL_Flip(screen);

    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    if (event.type ==  SDL_QUIT) { break; }
    if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP) { keyCatch = false; }
    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
      switch ( event.key.keysym.sym ) {
        case SDLK_ESCAPE : done = true; break;
        case SDLK_q      : done = true; break;
        case SDLK_F1     :  {
    if(!keyCatch){
              keyPress=true;
                     //this method is from another class.
                  io.printMessageAt("F1 is selected:",50,10);       
              currentOrb = (currentOrb+1) % orbs.size(); 
                      }
        break; 
        } 
        case SDLK_t : case SDLK_SPACE :
          if ( !keyPress ) {
            //something
          }
          break;
        case SDLK_p      : {
          if (!keyPress) {
            keyPress = true;
            //something
          }
          break;
        }
        default          : break;
      }
    }
  }
```

NOTE: i cannot give the entire code here.The above is my part what i am trying to do.

Comment: Why are you only grabbing a *single* event each frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check that your window manager or a hotkey daemon isn't consuming your F1's before they hit your process.

This works fine (F1 closes the program) on my system:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main( int, char** )
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING); 
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_ANYFORMAT);

    SDL_Event event;

    bool done = false;
    bool keyPress = false;
    while ( !done ) 
    {
        SDL_Flip(screen);

        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) 
        { 
            break; 
        }
        if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP) 
        { 
            keyPress = false; 
        }
        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch ( event.key.keysym.sym ) 
            {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE: 
            case SDLK_q: 
                done = true; 
                break;
            case SDLK_F1:  
                if(!keyPress)
                {
                    keyPress=true;
                    done = true;
                }
                break; 
            case SDLK_t:
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                if ( !keyPress ) 
                {
                    //something
                }
                break;
            case SDLK_p: 
                if (!keyPress) 
                {
                    keyPress = true;
                    //something
                }
                break;
            default: 
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I did notice that `keyCatch` was undefined.  I replaced it with `keyPress`.

Comment: hi gt the issue resolved just made use of flags,actually i wanted to execute some other function,so just a small issue,but thanks anyway.